# Better way of targeting parent node 3 levels up?

Tags: javascript

I currently have a working variable that targets the parent node 3 levels up

```js
searchClearSelector: '.search-form__clear', //The clear button on my input

  //Checks if there is a value in the input to clear then calls a function
  self._ClearActions = document.querySelectorAll(self.searchClearSelector);
if (self._ClearActions && self._ClearActions.length > 0) {
  for (const _Action of self._ClearActions) {
    _Action.addEventListener('click', self.ClearActionHandler);
  }
}

//Clear function
ClearActionHandler() {
  const self = this;
  const _Handle = this;
  const _HandleParent = parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  const _SearchInput = _HandleParent.querySelector('.search-form__input');
}
```

```html
<input className="search-form__input" placeholder="Enter text" />

<div className="search-form__actions">
  <button type="button" className="search-form__clear">Clear</button>
</div>
```

It works fine, but seems a little hacky - is there a better way for me to do this?

Thanks!

***EDIT - Updated code, i had to take a big chunk of the other stuff out as it is a huge file, the issue is with IE not clearing it (as it doesn't work with closest in vanilla JS)***

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your element structure.

Comment: For this kind of question we need to see what element you're selecting (and what `this` is); for that we need to see your HTML and the JavaScript in which you determine `this`.

Comment: thats best solution , [check](https://jsperf.com/jquery-get-3rd-level-parent)

Comment: You can try giving class to the 3rd parent and the access like this.closest(".class_name")

Comment: The reason I have to do it this way is because it isn't supported in IE (closest) it is more to get around an IE fix

Comment: can you please provide sample code here

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive function:

```js
function upperParents(element, levels) {
  if (levels == 1) return element.parentNode || element;
  if (levels < 1) return element;
  return upperParents(element.parentNode || element, levels - 1);
}

document.getElementById('btnwithparents').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(upperParents(this, 2));
});
```

```html
<div class="theparent">
  <span>
      <button id="btnwithparents">Search my parent 2 levels above</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I just fixed the first `if`. Sorry about that (I've been working with delphi lately and I'm getting confused some times)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a function like this:

```
const _HandleParent = parentsUntil(3, this); // 3rd parent

const parentsUntil = (num, elem) => {
   if(num <= 0) return;
   let node = elem;
   while(num--) node = node.parentNode;
   return node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `while` loop.

```
  var node = document.getElementById("id");
  var levels = 3;
  while (levels >= 0) {
      node = node.parentNode;
      levels--;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone gave solutions, here's another:

```
function getUpstream(el,lvl){
    if(!(el instanceof Node)){
        throw("Not a node!");
    }
    while((--lvl>=0)&&el){
        el = el.parentNode;
    }
    return el;
}
```

getUpstream(document.body,1)